# using ros::shutdown() in arduino code

Tags: ros, navigation, clearpath, rosserial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there guys,

I am trying to write an arduino based code for my robot, that would allow me to use a button on the PS3 joystick as an emergency kill-switch. I thought using ros::shutdown() would work, but apparently the arduino ros library doesn't recognize it as a function. Here is the code.

```
#include <ArduinoHardware.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

geometry_msgs::Twist msg;

void joyCall(const sensor_msgs::Joy& joy){
if (joy.buttons[14]==1)
  ros::shutdown();
}

ros::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Joy> sub("bluetooth_teleop/joy", &joyCall);
ros::Publisher pub("/cmd_vel", &msg);

void setup()
{
 nh.initNode();
 nh.advertise(pub);
 nh.subscribe(sub);
} 
void loop(){
 
  msg.linear.x=0.1;
  pub.publish(&msg);
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

Basically, I am publishing a constant velocity to the velocity node, but i want to kill the publisher as soon as a button on the joystick is pressed. However, I get this compiler error:

```
sketch_jun24a.ino: In function ‘void joyCall(const sensor_msgs::Joy&)’:
sketch_jun24a.ino:13:3: error: ‘shutdown’ is not a member of ‘ros’
```

Any help would be extremely useful. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212180/using-ros::shutdown()-in-arduino-code/) by [Adi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22721/adi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently ros::shutdown() is not a function in the arduino library, so that's that! In case anyone else evr has the same problem, remember this message!

---

Originally posted by [Adi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22721/adi/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since there is not a ros::shutdown something like this might be an alternative.

```
#include <ArduinoHardware.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
//Use a variable to store the speed
float speed = 0.1;

void joyCall(const sensor_msgs::Joy& joy){
if (joy.buttons[14]==1)
  speed = 0.0;
  
}

ros::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Joy> sub("bluetooth_teleop/joy", &joyCall);
ros::Publisher pub("/cmd_vel", &msg);

void setup()
{
 nh.initNode();
 nh.advertise(pub);
 nh.subscribe(sub);
} 
void loop(){

  msg.linear.x=speed;
  pub.publish(&msg);
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

or if you want the publisher to quit, this could be an option.

```
#include <ArduinoHardware.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
ros::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Joy> sub("bluetooth_teleop/joy", &joyCall);
ros::Publisher pub("/cmd_vel", &msg);

bool flag;

void joyCall(const sensor_msgs::Joy& joy){
  if (joy.buttons[14]==1)
  { //Set to zero and set flag so it quits publishing
    msg.linear.x = 0.0;
    pub.publish(&msg);
    flag = false;
  }  
}

void setup()
{
 flag = true;
 nh.initNode();
 nh.advertise(pub);
 nh.subscribe(sub);
}

void loop()
{
  if(flag)
  {
    msg.linear.x=0.1;
    pub.publish(&msg);
  }
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2015-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22721/adi/) on 2015-07-13**:
This is an interesting solution. I decided to write a universal killswitch package. What commands could I use to do a system wide shutdown, or simply shutdown all ros activity from within a c++ code?

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-07-13**:
Create a node that shutdown and then in your launch file add **required="true"** to that node.  Once the node shutdown the rest of the nodes will too.